# Query to get data in an own format in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to get all expenses in the format given below.so when I hit the `URL` `api/expenses` I get the result in the following manner and also when I call `api/expenses/<id>` it shows all expense with that expense id.

What Query should I use to get Output in the above format? How will my view look like? How can I separate `own` and `lend`?

Comment: Please add more data about your question...what is the required format, what does "following manner" mean and what own, lend are.

Comment: Hey @p.ry please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929711/reformat-django-rest-framework-serializer-to-get-output to get the whole context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are using django then you will have to write a serializer to convert the data to your desired format after you retrieve the modal instance from the query. There are many examples given in [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) documentation on how to write your custom serializer.  You will have to use the `to_representation` available on [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) link of documentation.

Comment: How can I add owe and lend field in output ?